# Overloads with different number data types

Tags: c#

Let's say that I have a method with 2 signatures:

```
void Foo(int a);
void Foo(long a, string s = null);
```

If I invoke `Foo` like this:

```
Foo(1);
```

It seems to call the first one of the two. Is it because numbers passed directly as an argument are treated as int32 by default? Where is this specified?

Comment: The literal value `1` _is_ an int.

Answer (score 6):

Section 2.4.4.2 (Integer literals) of the C# 5.0 specs states:

The type of an integer literal is determined as follows:

- If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.
- If the literal is suffixed by U or u, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: uint, ulong.
- If the literal is suffixed by L or l, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: long, ulong.
- If the literal is suffixed by UL, Ul, uL, ul, LU, Lu, lU, or lu, it is of type ulong.

---

So the first bullet applies to your case, as you have no suffix, and `1` fits into the first item in the list, `int`, so the integer literal `1` is of type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The literal value `1` alone is by default an `int` (`Int32`). If you want to explicitly call the version that takes a `long`, make sure you are passing a `long` value, for example:

```
Foo(1L);
```

[Servey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30125800/74757) does a superb job of explaining the *why*.